# Lua string with wildcard for spaces

Tags: lua

I want to search a long string for various items, the items might be like this;

```
"test     test"
"test            test"
"test test"
```

so I dont know how many spaces there might be between the tests so is there a wildcard I can use to basically tell lua its found if its "test" and "test" as long as there is at least 1 space character between the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try matching this pattern: `"test +test"`.

Here is some code:

```
function try(s)
    print(s:match("test +test")~=nil,s)
end

try"test     test"
try"test            test"
try"test test"
try"test,test"
try"test, test"
```

Comment: cool, how would that work with the "test" being a variable ie; test .. test would it be test ..+test?

Comment: @user1447683: `pattern = var .. " +" .. var` should work if var contains only letters (or more precisely, no magic characters).

Comment: @user1447683, `%s` will cater for tabs and even new lines, so if these are likely to appear in your input, sure, use `%s`.